# Accumulation point of $U = \{ (\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})\in\mathbb{R}^{2} : n = 1,2,3,...\}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $U = \{ (\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})\in\mathbb{R}^{2} : n = 1,2,3,...\}$. I need to find all accumulation points of the set U.

I understand that since $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$, the accumulation point would be $(0,0)$. However, I am struggling to provide a proof for it.

So currently, using the definition of convergence,

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $|\frac{1}{n} - 0| < \epsilon $.

As $\frac{1}{n} > 0$ the above proves that $\exists q\in {U}\setminus\{0\}  $ s.t. ${q}\in{B}(0,r)$  $\forall r>0 $

But I'm not sure how to prove that other points are not the accumulation point of $U$.

Comment: If you have struggled, you have something to show for it. For example, you surely know the definition of an accumulation point, and the definition of convergence of a sequence in $\mathbb R^2$. What went wrong when you tried to apply these definitions? You are intuitively on the right path.

Comment: You need two things. You need to show that $(0,0)$ is an accumulation point, and that no other point is an accumulation point.

Answer (score 1):

For any $\epsilon>0$ if
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^2}}\geq\epsilon$$ so $$n\leq\frac{\sqrt2}{\epsilon},$$ but there are finite such numbers $n$.